# Face has different shading that rest of object

Tags: modeling, shaders, faces

This particular face  has different shading than the rest of the object and i don't know why.
[image]

Comment: If you could upload the blend file, that would help

Comment: I sort of solved the problem by deleting the faces and re smooth shading them. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, in my case it was because of duplicate points, <kbd>W</kbd> *> Remove Doubles* fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Generally we prefer answers which explain how to do the steps mentioned; I've taken the liberty of [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) your answer to include where to find the *Remove Doubles* operator. If you don't agree with my edits, please feel free to roll them back and/or submit more edits of your own.

Answer (score 3):

Go into edit mode, select the face(s) that are shaded funny.  Click on the shading/UVs tab on the tools menu, if you don't see the toolshelf, press <kbd>T</kbd>.  After clicking on the shading/UVs tab in the toolshelf [NB: "Shading/UV" was in a panel on the main toolshelf through version 2.69; the buttons were moved to a tab starting with version 2.7] click "flip direction" and it will flip direction of the normals of the face(s). Alternatively you could select the whole mesh and click recalculate, however that doesn't always work.

Comment: Nope, the face flips and the side is invisible, i don't think that its a normal problem.

Comment: Do you have any materials applied to it?

Comment: Yes. I found that the up face has a lot of faces adjacent to it that shouldn't be there, i'll try deleting them and see if it solves the problem. Edit: It didn't.

Comment: It could be the material applied even though you are in solid view.  I have a mesh I've made and sharp changes in material still change the object slightly even when not rendering or in material view.

Answer (score 2):

You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> while all the mesh is selected in edit mode or go to the Toolshelf and under the Shading tab, under the Normal Section, click 'Recalculate'.

[NB: "Shading/UV" was in a panel on the main toolshelf through version 2.69]

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Does it have Smooth Shading applied?

Comment: Yes. I also have an edge split modifier applied if it helps.

Comment: If you've tried the above advice and it still hasn't helped, you really should provide a .blend so we can examine the problem in detail.